# Django dynamic url resolve in javascript code

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have this code in my javascript.

```
let link = <a class='${!questionnaire.exam ? 'ajax-btn' : ''} card__item ${!questionnaire.active ? 'card__item--inactive' : ''}' href="{% url '${questionnaire.id}' %}"></a>
```

But the url of the `<a>`tag  does not resolve correctly after I insert this code in my html with javascript.

Answer (score -2):

If you expect to pass js variables to template code, then you really need to learn about the difference between frontend (client) and backend (server) - and actually about the whole HHTP protocol.

Your template is rendered by the server (backend), then the generated HTML is returned to the browser (frontend) as the HTTP response's content. Then, if there's some js code in the HTML and your browser knows how to interpreted js, the js code will be executed by the browser (frontend). At this point, the request/response cycle is finished, the communication closed (until next request) etc.

So of course, what you're trying to do just can not work...

Comment: i replace the  html content with Jquery html(), in my AJAX success method.Then the communication is not close, is it?

Comment: Please re-read my answer. The template code is executed on the server, the js code on the browser. This means that by the time the js code is executed, you're not in a Django template but in the generated markup, and there's no template code to execute anymore (and nothing that could execute it anyway).  This has nothing to do with Ajax (an "ajax" request is just a HTTP request, period) nor JQuery. Actually, this has nothing to do with Django templates themselves, it's the same for any server-side code generating HTML.

Comment: And yes, by the time you're in the ajax success handler, the template has been rendered, the generated HTML returned as part of the HTTP response and the communication has been closed. "Ajax" is just plain HTTP request/response cycle. Really, __learn about the HTTP protocol__, it __will__ save you a __lot__ of time. Trying to do web programming without undertanding the HTTP protocol is like trying to solve an equation without knowing algebra.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I understand now.